# fetch table in slider

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to fetch mysql table in simple slider
the table contain users and each user have many information like name location .. etc.
this is my code :

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
$id=$_POST['id'];
$query="select * from users";
$query2=mysql_query($query)
or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query2)){ 
?>
                      <div class="course_demo">
                          <ul id="flexiselDemo3">   
                            <li><img src="images/pic4.jpg" /><div class="desc">
                                <h3><?php echo $row['username']; ?><br><span class="m_text">Spinning</span></h3>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor<br> sit amet, consectetuer.</p>
                                <div class="coursel_list">
                                    <i class="heart1"> </i>
                                    <i class="like"> </i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="coursel_list1">
                                    <i class="twt"> </i>
                                    <i class="fb"> </i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                            </div></li>                                                 
                        </ul>
                <script type="text/javascript">
            $(window).load(function() {
                $("#flexiselDemo3").flexisel({
                    visibleItems: 4,
                    animationSpeed: 1000,
                    autoPlay: true,
                    autoPlaySpeed: 3000,            
                    pauseOnHover: true,
                    enableResponsiveBreakpoints: true,
                    responsiveBreakpoints: { 
                        portrait: { 
                            changePoint:480,
                            visibleItems: 1
                        }, 
                        landscape: { 
                            changePoint:640,
                            visibleItems: 2
                        },
                        tablet: { 
                            changePoint:768,
                            visibleItems: 2
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexisel.js"></script>
      </div>
<?php } ?>
```

the problem is the slider fetch only the first row in all slides fetch the first row only
how can fix this problem?

Comment: i guess you need to put script tag outside while loop

Comment: I'v trying this but not working